# Error in executing two groupbys in sparkSQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am new to sparksql and i was trying to experiment certain queries with that.

This is the query i am trying to execute

```
sqlContext.sql(SELECT id , category ,AVG(mark) FROM data GROUP BY id, category)
```

I am not getting proper output when i run the query.

instead of actual value of category i am getting some value as 1,2,3.

I am stuck at this weird error for long time

but when i do simple select statement and one group by its working perfectly

```
sqlContext.sql(SELECT id , category  FROM data)

sqlContext.sql(SELECT id  ,AVG(mark) FROM data GROUP BY id)
```

What is wrong? Does SPARKSQL has something to do with multiple group by.

right now i am running this complex query

```
sqlContext.sql(SELECT data.id , data.category, AVG(id_avg.met_avg) FROM (SELECT  id, AVG(mark) AS met_avg FROM data GROUP BY id) AS id_avg, data GROUP BY data.category, data.id)
```

This works, but taking a longer time to execute.

Please Help

Sample data:

```
|id | category | marks  
| 1 |        a |  40  
| 2 |        b |  44 
| 3 |        a |  50  
| 4 |        b |  40  
| 1 |        a |  30
```

The output should be:

```
|id | category | avg  
| 1 |        a |  35  
| 2 |        b |  44 
| 3 |        a |  50  
| 4 |        b |  40
```

Comment: You really need to provide two things: 1. `sample data` just a few columns and a few rows would suffice, and 2. the `expected result` from that sample. My immediate guess is you should stop using ID in those queries but I can't tell without those 2 items

Comment: Sample data
id | category | marks
 1 |    a     | 40
 2 |    a     | 44
 1 |    b     | 50
 2 |    b     | 40
 2 |    b     | 30

the output should be 

 id | category | avg
  1 |    a     | 40
  2 |    a     | 44
  1 |    b     | 50
  2 |    b     | 35

Comment: could you verify that sample data and expected result - I edited the question for that as I didn't understand it

Comment: i edited the question please check it

Comment: that is the most odd way of "averaging" I have ever seen. 5 lines of input which are "averaged" back to 5 lines of output but only one average is output, all others as the unaltered raw input. weird. the average of 3 input lines is one output line (average for category a is (40+50+30)/3 = 40; the average for b is one line also 44+40/2 = 42. I would suggest you rethink the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT
      data.id
    , data.category
    , AVG(mark)
FROM data
GROUP BY
      data.id
    , data.category
```

Based on this sample data:

```
|id | category | marks  
| 1 |        a |  40  
| 2 |        b |  44 
| 3 |        a |  50  
| 4 |        b |  40  
| 1 |        a |  30
```

The output WILL be this:

```
|id | category | avg  
| 1 |        a |  35  
| 2 |        b |  44 
| 3 |        a |  50  
| 4 |        b |  40
```

and, the following expected row cannot be produced using `group by`:

```
| 5 |        a |  30
```

Comment: if you add ID into that query you will achieve nothing because each ID is unique so "group by" on a unique ID will "average" one row so every row will simply be a mimic of the original input. It isn't sensible and either you are not expressing yourself clearly - or you aren't grasping the concept of averaging &/or what "group by" does.

Comment: no id is not unique in this case i need average for each id and for each category.. that is my usecase

Comment: `group by` will form the unique `combinations` of ID and Category. From the sample data displayed as I write this, thise unique combinations are: |1|a|   |2|b|  |3|a|   |4|b|   so you can ONLY get 4 rows in the result, not 5

Comment: i think its a bug in spark 

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-spark-user/201406.mbox/%3C80833ADD533E324CA05C160E41B63661026C8906@shsmsx102.ccr.corp.intel.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug in sparksql.
Try using the next version. Its fixed.

i got the proper output by using spark-1.0.2

it worked with pure scala code also. Try either of them :)